# error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler is not solved

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to use Address sanitizer in rust with this manual(https://github.com/japaric/rust-san),
but when I build this code with command `RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitier=address" cargo rustc -- --emit=llvm-ir`, it cause error like this;

error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -Z sanitier=address --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=cfg` (exit status: 1)
--- stderr
error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler'

I think that "the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler" is problem, so I set up to nightly compiler with
`rustup install nightly`, `rustup default nightly`, but it cause same error when I build with that command.

How should I do?

Comment: If it caused the *same* error, then you must be using a [toolchain override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html).  But are you *sure* it's the exact same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should build your code with command:

```sh
RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitier=address" cargo run ${your-binary-name} --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -- --emit=llvm-ir
```

This works for me to check [example](https://github.com/japaric/rust-san/blob/master/asan/examples/out-of-bounds.rs) in manual:

```sh
RUSTFLAGS="-Z sanitizer=address" cargo run --example out-of-bounds --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -- --emit=llvm-ir

**==618620==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fffbcbf1250 at pc 0x55adfda84e90 bp 0x7fffbcbf1210 sp 0x7fffbcbf1208
READ of size 4 at 0x7fffbcbf1250 thread T0
    #0 0x55adfda84e8f in out_of_bounds::main::hf228b092630ab849 /tmp/rust-san/asan/examples/out-of-bounds.rs:3:22
    #1 0x55adfda846fa in core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once::h84454ea25b7d75ab /rustc/f1f721e64014863f41c1a386b04af04c2de25321/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
    #2 0x55adfda84a94 in std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::hbc7697f2c0b7e35d /rustc/f1f721e64014863f41c1a386b04af04c2de25321/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:122:18
    #3 0x55adfda853a3 in std::rt::lang_start::_$u7b$$u7b$closure$u7d$$u7d$::h01c2d6f3a231ead0 /rustc/f1f721e64014863f41c1a386b04af04c2de25321/library/std/src/rt.rs:145:18
    #4 0x55adfda9704d in core::ops::function::impls::_$LT$impl$u20$core..ops..function..FnOnce$LT$A$GT$$u20$for$u20$$RF$F$GT$::call_once::hfce3f72e51a03fc4 /rustc/f1f721e64014863f41c1a386b04af04c2de25321/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:280:13
**
```

According to the manual, you should always pass `--target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` to Cargo.

> Be sure to *always* pass `--target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` to Cargo or else you'll end up sanitizing the build scripts that Cargo runs or run into compilation error if your crate depends on a dylib.

And you could check your toolchain version with:

```sh
> rustup default
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
```